# Struggling with removing stop words using nltk

Tags: nlp, nltk

I'm trying to remove the stop words from "I don't like ice cream." I have defined:

`stop_words = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))`

and the function

```
def stop_word_remover(text):
    return [word for word in text if word.lower() not in stop_words]
```

But when I apply the function to the string in question, I get this list:

```
[' ', 'n', '’', ' ', 'l', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'c', 'e', ' ', 'c', 'r', 'e', '.']
```

which, when joining the strings together as in `''.join(stop_word_remover("I don’t like ice cream."))`, I get

`' n’ lke ce cre.'`

which is not what I was expecting.

Any tips on where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`word for word in text` iterates over characters of `text` (not over words!)
you should change your code as below:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 

stop_words = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))

def stop_word_remover(text):
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    word_list = [word for word in word_tokens if word.lower() not in stop_words]
    return " ".join(word_list)

stop_word_remover("I don't like ice cream.")

## 'n't like ice cream .'
```